# Can I graph memory usage for windows in cacti?

Tags: windows, cacti

Can I graph memory usage in windows for cacti?
We are running cacti version 0.8.7i on windows.

When I go into a windows server device and go to the "Associated Graph Templates" section. There is a drop down list "Add Graph Template"
I see one that says "Linux - Memory Usage" but I assume this only works for linux machines?
I also see Cisco Cpu Usage. Can I use any of these ?

Comment: Cannot get counters via SNMP?

Comment: What do you mean by this?  The drop down for adding a graph template has one item for SNMP it says "SNMP Generic OID Template".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer: Yes.

long answer: Install the windows SNMP server. From there on you will have to figure out which SNMP ID holds the windows memory. (cheat:

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.5.6 – Total physical memory
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.6.6 – Used physical memory
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.6.6 – Total virtual memory ["virtual"="swap" in Windows lingo]
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.6.6 – Used virtual memory)
```

After this: Profit!

Have a look at this site as well: http://www.netuality.ro/monitoring-windows-servers-with-snmp/tools/20060512/

Comment: Ok this looks helpful, but I cant see how to plot multiple points (multiple legend keys) in cacti like the example in the article. I  have it plotting physical memory and I want to add physical memory used.  The UI for cacti isnt as straightforward about stuff like this.  Someone asked a similiar question in the comments of that blog but the answer goes to a broken link... :(

Comment: The documents are located here: http://docs.cacti.net/manual:088 there is a whole section on how to build graphs and its a bit to much to explain here. Suggest taking the guide and just start playing.

Comment: Right unfortunately the help files do not show how to plot more then one key value on a graph.

Comment: it does and says it in this chapter: http://docs.cacti.net/manual:088:3_templates.2_graph_template#walkthroughmy_first_graph_template

Comment: Cool I did not find that, I will go through it thanks for taking the time out to help.